# How can I determine whether Background App Refresh is enabled for an Apple Watch app?

Tags: ios, watchos

In an iPhone app, it's easy to check whether a user has Background App Refresh enabled for an app with `UIApplication.shared.backgroundRefreshStatus` (documentation here).

For Apple Watch, a user can go into either the **Watch** app on iPhone or the **Settings** app on Apple Watch and go to **General > Background App Refresh** and turn it off for specific apps or all apps.

Is there an equivalent to `UIApplication.shared.backgroundRefreshStatus` or some other way that I can use to determine if the user has disabled Background App Refresh on Apple Watch for my app or all apps?

Answer (score -1):

You can't (iOS 13.6.1, Watchos 6.2.8)

The method for registering background app refresh:

[scheduleBackgroundRefresh(withPreferredDate:userInfo:scheduledCompletion:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextension/1650848-schedulebackgroundrefresh)

does not give an error if Background App refresh is disabled for the specific app and for all apps. And there's no other way